# Is there an ArrayList Listner in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to know if there some way to listen an ArrayList. And if it's added some item, the method must finallize. Like the follow's code, but in a better way:

```
 //where form.getRetorno() is an ArrayList<String>
 private void process(ManifestacaoForm form) {
    validaJustificativa(form);

    if (form.getRetorno().isEmpty()) {
        TEvento evento = criaEvento(form);
        if(form.getRetorno().isEmpty()) {
            NfeDadosMsg nfeDadosMsg = criaNfeDadosMsg(evento, form);
            if(form.getRetorno().isEmpty()) {
                enviaReq(nfeDadosMsg, form);
            }
        }
    }
    setSuccess(form);

}
```

Comment: No but there's nothing stopping you from creating a class that works like a container that does some extra stuff when an item is added, and is backed by an ArrayList.

Comment: JavaFX has an observable list.  If your application isn’t a JavaFX application, I would suggest making your own class which wraps a List (or extends ArrayList, but that will be a lot more difficult, as you will have to override a lot of methods, including the iterator and subList methods).

Comment: look at this https://github.com/Ruslan08/trigger-collections , you could contribute there or suggest something new

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could do is extend AbstractList, have an ArrayList (or whatever implementation) as a member variable, override the methods. NOTE: this isn't tested, just giving you ideas.

```
public class ActiveList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Collection<EventListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    private void fireItemAdded(T item) {
        //iterate through listeners and send events.
    }

    private void fireAddFailed(T item) {

    }

    private void fireRemoveFailed(int idx) {

    }

    private void fireItemRemoved(T item) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        boolean added = super.add(item);
        if (added) {
            fireItemAdded(item);
        } else {
            fireAddFailed(item);
        }
        return added;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int idx) {
        T itemRemoved = super.remove(idx);
        if (itemRemoved == null) {
            fireRemoveFailed(idx);
        } else {
            fireItemRemoved(itemRemoved);
        }
        return itemRemoved;
    }
    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using Observable :

```
public class ManifestacaoForm extends Observable {
     private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

     public void addMessage(String message){
         myList.add(message);
         setChanged();
         notifyObservers();
     }
}

public class ManifestacaoObserver implements Observer {
     Observable manifestacaoForm;
     List<String> myList;

     public ManifestacaoObserver(Observable manifestacaoForm) {
        this.manifestacaoForm = manifestacaoForm;
        this.manifestacaoForm.addObserver(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void update(Observable manifestacaoFormSubject, Object arg) {
        if(manifestacaoFormSubject instanceof ManifestacaoForm) {
            ManifestacaoForm manifestacaoForm = (ManifestacaoForm) 
            manifestacaoFormSubject;
            myList= manifestacaoForm.getMyList();
            if(myList.size()>1) {
                 // do whatever you want
            }
        }
    }
 }

  public class Foo {
        private void process(ManifestacaoForm form) {
            new ManifestacaoObserver(form);
            validaJustificativa(form);
            TEvento evento = criaEvento(form);
            NfeDadosMsg nfeDadosMsg = criaNfeDadosMsg(evento, form);
            enviaReq(nfeDadosMsg, form);
            setSuccess(form);
        }
    }
```